# Missing Design Tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The Design Tab in Android Studio has disappeared after I download the latest version of SDK.

Below is the screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHmiR.png)

I have tried the methods suggested in the posts similar to my issue, which is stated as follows:

- Try Designer button in the right (I do not have this button)
- Try View -> Tools Window -> Designer (This button is greyed)

I saw someone suggested that this is due to the SDK location is not set correctly, nevertheless, I am not sure how I should re-set the SDK location or even check whether the SDK location is wrong.

Comment: You ARE in the design window right now. Before the upgrade, was it in the right hand side?

Comment: Yes it was in the right hand side, but I don't have the palette that allows me to interact with

Answer (score 0):

If you update Android SDK so mostly you only need to switch to a lower API:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ju3br0jlccqacd/api.png?dl=0

The Android SDK is a problem that bothers designer render.

But if it does not correct this error so it is usually a mistake android studios. Android Studio is a program with a lot of errors.

Sorry I´m using google translate.

Edit:
Or go to android SDK manager and download the android tools and android reposity and android assets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded your android studio and you are viewing your old projects after this, you will not be able to see the design tab. So, create a new project and just import all the old java codes into new one.